# How to code login to backend in joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, login

I am making my own component in Joomla, which provides me login through an external site.

Last issue I need to solve is the login. When I trigger `onUserLogin` event by:

```
$dispatcher->triggerEvent('onUserLogin', array($response, $options));
```

It works, but only for front-end site.

What I have to do to login to the back-end? Is there any trick which would help me, for example manually create session and insert to db?

If not, what plugin method do I have to override?

Comment: front-end and back-end are two different sites.

Comment: Can you help me with login to backend? Very important for me Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I used code below to login to the backend automatically, and it works fine, the location where I put these code is: **/plugins/system/mysociallogin/mysociallogin.php**

The mistake I made before is that I requested to the wrong url. If you want to login to the backend, don't forget to request to **/administrator/index.php**, the frontend and backend are two different sites in fact.

```
if (isset ($identity->UserId))
{    
    require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_login/models/login.php';
    $adminApp = JApplication::getInstance('administrator');

    $model       = JModelLegacy::getInstance('login', 'LoginModel');
    $credentials = array('username' => $user_login,
                         'password' => $user_identity_id);
    $return      = "index.php";

    $ret = $adminApp->login($credentials, array('action' => 'core.login.admin', 'entry_url' => '/administrator/index.php?option=com_users&task=user.login'));

    if ($ret && !($ret instanceof Exception))
    {
        // Only redirect to an internal URL.
        if (JUri::isInternal($return))
        {
            // If &tmpl=component - redirect to index.php
            if (strpos($return, 'tmpl=component') === false)
            {
                $adminApp->redirect($return);
            }
            else
            {
                $adminApp->redirect('index.php');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

update Nov 4, 2018

finally, I found login to the backend is as easy as a few code below to achieve:

$options['group'] = 'Public Backend';
$options['autoregister'] = false;
$options['action'] = 'core.login.admin';

$response = new stdClass();
$response->username = "su";

JPluginHelper::importPlugin ('user');
$result = $app->triggerEvent ('onUserLogin', array ((array) $response, $options)); /* key point*/

just FYI~